# Mysql Global variable 'innodb_file_format' value differs in master and slave

Tags: mysql, file, format, innodb

While debugging the slave is lagging behind master, I have observed global variable **innodb_file_format** differs in slave and master machine. Master is set to *Barracuda* and slave is set to *Antelope*.
Does it have the impact on slave lagging?

Comment: What have you done so far to have the need to ask?

Comment: So I was going through slow queries, found some 14 slow queries in the timespan of 22mins. But the slave lagged 5000 secs. Then I was going through any difference in global variable values. Found 2 main variable's value mismatch **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit** and **innodb_file_format**. **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit** is set to 2 in master while 1 in slave. Which definitely contributing in slave lag. I also want to know about **innodb_file_format**, can this be also signficant in case of slave lag?

Answer (score 0):

5000 seconds is 83 minutes.  That is more than 22 minutes, so something else is going on.

The file_format *probably* would not explain the difference.  What is `binlog_format`?  (That probably does not matter either, just want to get it in play.)

Let's see the slowest queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant table(s).  We can probably suggest how to speed some of them up.

`innofb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` *may* have a big impact *IO* performance.  Do you have HDD or SSD?  How many transactions were run in those 22 minutes?  `=2` is faster, but less safe -- generally good for a Slave.  `=1` is slower, but safer -- generally good for a Master.  I suggest you got them backwards.

*Usually* a slave lag is caused by transactions are run in parallel (from different connections) on the Master.  Is that the case?  And the Slave is single threaded.  What version of MySQL?  Only newer versions even have the option of parallelism.